# I have a problem while adding double quotes to string values. The second quotes is displaying far from the values

Tags: java, android

taking the values as sharedPrefernece and saving as String
   ///get date

```
SharedPreferences shareddate = this.getSharedPreferences("DateInUpcoming", 0);
selectedDate = (shareddate.getString("DateInUpcoming", null));
Log.d("SharedPreference", "DateInUpcoming is "+selectedDate);
```

Adding  double quotes to the string values:

```
    char ch='"';

    String value = (ch + selectedDate + ch);
    Log.d("SharedPreference",""+value);
```

The image is also attached from logcat

Any help would be appreciated.
[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Stq.png)

Comment: There is no issue with this, you are not adding double-quotes by default its adding.

Comment: `ch + selectedDate + ch` behaves the way you expect. The braces around it and `""+value` are obsolete. If there's an issue it is already there with `selectedDate` or introduced by `Log.d`. Just [debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems?noredirect=1&lq=1) the thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still having the issue, here is a solve -

```java
    String value = ("\"" + selectedDate + "\"");
    Log.d("SharedPreference",""+value);
```

Comment: Your method should work fine, however I find this to be a more efficient way.